# jQuery scrollTo in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollto

I have a problem with jQuery ScrollTo in Chrome, it works good i FF but in Chrome it looks bad. I read posts about it but in my theme code is different i think. Please help

```
 ;
 (function ($) {
     var h = $.scrollTo = function (a, b, c) {
         $(window).scrollTo(a, b, c)
     };
     h.defaults = {
         axis: 'xy',
         duration: parseFloat($.fn.jquery) >= 1.3 ? 0 : 1,
         limit: true
     };
     h.window = function (a) {
         return $(window)._scrollable()
     };
     $.fn._scrollable = function () {
         return this.map(function () {
             var a = this,
                 isWin = !a.nodeName || $.inArray(a.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe', '#document', 'html', 'body']) != -1;
             if (!isWin) return a;
             var b = (a.contentWindow || a).document || a.ownerDocument || a;
             return /webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || b.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ? b.body : b.documentElement
         })
     };
     $.fn.scrollTo = function (e, f, g) {
         if (typeof f == 'object') {
             g = f;
             f = 0
         }
         if (typeof g == 'function') g = {
             onAfter: g
         };
         if (e == 'max') e = 9e9;
         g = $.extend({}, h.defaults, g);
         f = f || g.duration;
         g.queue = g.queue && g.axis.length > 1;
         if (g.queue) f /= 2;
         g.offset = both(g.offset);
         g.over = both(g.over);
         return this._scrollable().each(function () {
             if (e == null) return;
             var d = this,
                 $elem = $(d),
                 targ = e,
                 toff, attr = {}, win = $elem.is('html,body');
             switch (typeof targ) {
                 case 'number':
                 case 'string':
                     if (/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ)) {
                         targ = both(targ);
                         break
                     }
                     targ = $(targ, this);
                     if (!targ.length) return;
                 case 'object':
                     if (targ.is || targ.style) toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset()
             }
             $.each(g.axis.split(''), function (i, a) {
                 var b = a == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
                     pos = b.toLowerCase(),
                     key = 'scroll' + b,
                     old = d[key],
                     max = h.max(d, a);
                 if (toff) {
                     attr[key] = toff[pos] + (win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos]);
                     if (g.margin) {
                         attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin' + b)) || 0;
                         attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border' + b + 'Width')) || 0
                     }
                     attr[key] += g.offset[pos] || 0;
                     if (g.over[pos]) attr[key] += targ[a == 'x' ? 'width' : 'height']() * g.over[pos]
                 } else {
                     var c = targ[pos];
                     attr[key] = c.slice && c.slice(-1) == '%' ? parseFloat(c) / 100 * max : c
                 }
                 if (g.limit && /^\d+$/.test(attr[key])) attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min(attr[key], max);
                 if (!i && g.queue) {
                     if (old != attr[key]) animate(g.onAfterFirst);
                     delete attr[key]
                 }
             });
             animate(g.onAfter);

             function animate(a) {
                 $elem.animate(attr, f, g.easing, a && function () {
                     a.call(this, e, g)
                 })
             }
         }).end()
     };
     h.max = function (a, b) {
         var c = b == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
             scroll = 'scroll' + c;
         if (!$(a).is('html,body')) return a[scroll] - $(a)[c.toLowerCase()]();
         var d = 'client' + c,
             html = a.ownerDocument.documentElement,
             body = a.ownerDocument.body;
         return Math.max(html[scroll], body[scroll]) - Math.min(html[d], body[d])
     };

     function both(a) {
         return typeof a == 'object' ? a : {
             top: a,
             left: a
         }
     }
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you define looks bad? Chill on the downvotes people he/she just joined SO.

Comment: In addition to what @PatsyIssa asked, can you explain what the code you're showing us is? Where did you get it? What is it supposed to do? Anything that might help us understand your situation and problem.

Comment: I bought a HTML template. I've uploaded it to ftp server and i've tried it. It is jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js i thought it is a reason. Site when work in Chrome, scrolls non-seamless. In firefox it works good.

Comment: you should show us some code preview on jsfiddle or like this platforms.Otherwise, I think anybody cannot help you

Comment: sorry what is jsfiddle ?  You mean in html file ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ you can add css/javascript/HTML code and preview it

Comment: but what You need to see ?
I paste whole code from scrollTo plugin file and i ask if You can tell me why in chrome scrolling is non-seamless

Comment: just give a link to your website to see what is your target

Comment: [link]http://markizasklep.website.pl/altea/agency-index.html

Comment: please check this site in FF and Chrome